# Orient fails to write last commit

Tags: orientdb

I am running into the following which is kind of odd

OS X 10.11 Orient 2.1.11

I am grabbing data from a memory only graph (thread a) to feed graph g (thread b)

The logic in thread b has worked reliably for long time. It can handle super nodes of several million vertices.

The problem I am running into now is: some commits changes are not reflected on disk, let alone in subsequents read. All the reads and writes to g are executed by thread b.

The commits succeed.

I am embedding orient with with following

new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:" + f.getAbsolutePath()).setupPool(1, 2));

then setting autoStartTx to false.

If I let the logic run, it is the last commit that is missing. If I step through code it can be several commits that are missing.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using JVM 1.7

Comment: Hi, I think small test will be handy, otherwise it is hard to get what problem really is.

Comment: Hello! I will change a couple of lines/methods to make one overall commit instead of dripping commits. If that works, then we'll an starting point because I can not even figure out how to isolate it in a small test case

Comment: Hi! I changed the code to one overall commit. It works. But I also found out that I was using -Xm 512m. Probably not sufficient for all the things that were happening. So let's leave it for now and if I run into the same problem, I will try to filter it more. Thanks!!!